# Precondition Swift 3

Tags: ios, concurrency, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I am following the last conference of Apple about the GCD on this link:https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016-720/?time=33 
I got to the point where it speaks of the precondition here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016-720/?time=1267, a new feature in Swift 3.
Arrived at this point: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016-720/?time=1474 is used this:
.register(observer:, queue:)
[image]
my question: how this function retains object `BusyController`?
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=1550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask how this `register(observer:queue:)` retains `BusyController`.

First, let's step back: Let's not get lost in the details of his example. He's not saying that it *will* establish a strong reference, merely that it *could*, and therefore you should be cautious about just trying to clean up in `deinit`.

So, how could `DataTransform` retain `BusyController`? It simply could maintain a strong reference to its `observer`. Note, do not conflate this custom `register` method example with the standard observer methods: They're just saying "imagine that the `DataTransform` object established a strong reference to `BusyController`..."

But, as he goes on to say "but you're skilled developers, and you know how to fix this problem; use a `weak` reference." So, generally, we wouldn't write observation methods that maintained strong references to their observers.

But, as he goes on to say, even if you're good about avoiding strong reference cycles, the object graph can get pretty complicated, so it's not always a good idea to rely upon `deinit` to clean up. He's advocating for an explicit `invalidate` process, and possibly using preconditions to test that the object has been invalidated by the time `deinit` is called.